# WPF web browser Project, decreasing window size make tool bar items disappear

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, browser

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
        <TabControl x:Name="PossTabControl" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <TabItem Header="Tab Page 1" Margin="-9,-2,0,-2">
                <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1" Margin="0,36,0,0"></WebBrowser>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem RenderTransformOrigin="0.094,0.5" Margin="-2,-2,2,-2" Height="25">
                <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="Images/Add.ico" Width="19" Height="15"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ToolBar Margin="0,28,0,342" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="Auto">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="btnBack" Height="30" Margin="0,-2,0,-3" Width="30" Foreground="#FFF02525">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="Images/Back.ico" Stretch="Fill">
                        </Image>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnFoward" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="2.5,-1,0,-2">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="Images/Forward.ico" Stretch="Fill">
                        </Image>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnHome" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="2.5,-1,0,-2">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="Images/Home.ico" Stretch="Fill">
                        </Image>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
                <ProgressBar x:Name="SocialProgress" Margin="2.9,-1,0,-2" Width="546" Height="30"></ProgressBar>
                <Button x:Name="btnGo" Width="40" Margin="5,-1,0,-2" Content="GO" Click="btnGo_Click">

                </Button>
                <ComboBox x:Name="SearchCombo" Margin="0,3,-5,2" Width="51" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="Images/Google.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="Images/Yahoo.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="Images/Bing.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="Images/Amazon.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="Images/Ebay.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="Images/Twitter.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="Images/Wikipedia.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBox Margin="5,3,5,2" Name="SearchBar" Width="290"/>
                <Image Source="Images/Magnifying.png" Width="30" Height="30"></Image>
                <Button Width="94" Height="30"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolBar>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox x:Name="AddressBar" Height="31" Margin="107,33,590,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent" FontSize="20" Width="548"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button x:Name="btnMinimize" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="858,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Height="27" Click="btnMinimize_Click">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="Images/Minimize.ico" Stretch="Fill">
                    </Image>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnMaximize" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Height="27" Click="btnMaximize_Click">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="Images/Maximize.png" Stretch="Fill">
                    </Image>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnClose" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="28" Height="27" Click="btnClose_Click">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="Images/Close.ico" Stretch="Fill">
                    </Image>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

My WPF web browser Project .. while decreasing window size,Tool bar items disappear when border touches last button in toolbar,Any Help Solving the problem would be appreciated [Please Note this my first WPF project .. so i have limited knowledge in the subject

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all I would recommend avoid setting static Height and Width for the controls, better to use Grid container control to place your controls. Do that and many of your problem regarding to arranging control will be solved automatically.
Paste this XAML in editor and check how Grid can be used to place your controls

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button x:Name="btnMinimize" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="28" Height="27" >
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="Images/Minimize.ico" Stretch="Fill">
                </Image>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnMaximize" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" Width="28" Height="27">
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="Images/Maximize.png" Stretch="Fill">
                </Image>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnClose" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0" Width="28" Height="27" >
            <Button.Content>
                <Image Source="Images/Close.ico" Stretch="Fill">
                </Image>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>

    <TextBox x:Name="AddressBar" Background="Transparent" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <ToolBar Grid.Row="2" Height="40">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="btnBack" Height="30" Margin="0,-2,0,-3" Width="30" Foreground="#FFF02525">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="Images/Back.ico" Stretch="Fill">
                    </Image>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnFoward" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="2.5,-1,0,-2">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="Images/Forward.ico" Stretch="Fill">
                    </Image>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnHome" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="2.5,-1,0,-2">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="Images/Home.ico" Stretch="Fill">
                    </Image>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <ProgressBar x:Name="SocialProgress" Margin="2.9,-1,0,-2" Width="546" Height="30"></ProgressBar>
            <Button x:Name="btnGo" Width="40" Margin="5,-1,0,-2" Content="GO">

            </Button>
            <ComboBox x:Name="SearchCombo" Margin="0,3,-5,2" Width="51" SelectedIndex="0">
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="Images/Google.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="Images/Yahoo.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="Images/Bing.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="Images/Amazon.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="Images/Ebay.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="Images/Twitter.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="Images/Wikipedia.ico" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox Margin="5,3,5,2" Name="SearchBar" Width="290"/>
            <Image Source="Images/Magnifying.png" Width="30" Height="30"></Image>
            <Button Width="94" Height="30"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </ToolBar>

    <TabControl x:Name="PossTabControl" Grid.Row="3">
        <TabItem Header="Tab Page 1" >
            <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1" ></WebBrowser>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem >
            <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="Images/Add.ico" Width="19" Height="15"></Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>



</Grid>
```

Comment: In your case it happening because of that Margin="0,28,0,342" you set for Toolbar to place it.

Comment: but by removing margin placing the tool bar would be difficult

Comment: That is why I suggested to use Grid to place your controls. It is similar control to what we had in HTML as Table. You can divide it in RowDefinition and ColumnDefinition and place your controls in desired row column.